# material ui grid and breakpoints, use lg but not md or xs

Tags: material-ui, breakpoints

I used **material ui grid** and it's **breakpoints**.
I want to see this grid item in lg size and be removed in md and xs size.
It didn't work!

```
<Grid item lg={3} md={false} xs={false}>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code what you have for this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: `false` is the default value for breakpoints so probably this does not make that much of a difference. Can you please explain what you would like to achieve? Maybe if you try to add `12` as value for `md` and `xs` then in those breakpoints the `<Grid />` item will be rendered as full row width. Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Please be more specific about “but it didn’t work”. Explain what it is currently doing and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Grid doesn’t have functionality for removing grid items for different breakpoints, it just supports changing the layout for different breakpoints.

Comment: @RyanCogswell So what is {false} used for?

Comment: @BanafsheAlipour `false` is the default. It is the same as not specifying anything for that breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with **Material-UI** ***Grid*** it dose not provide this,

you need to use **Hidden** it same as Grid work on breakpoints but to hide and show components.

[**Hidden Docs**](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/)

```
 <Hidden xsUp>
      <YourComponent />
 </Hidden>
```

its easy to use and work like charm.